# drupal issues on page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

A customer has asked me if can help on their drupal site as they got errors/warnings on it and can't see the site, I have never used drupal but looking at the errors/warnings, I am wondering if the path is incorrect but can't see where to change the path, I found the settings.php but most of the code is commented out, I thought there may be some sort of config file that has the path in it

The errors/warnings on the site are below

```
Warning: include(/var/webroot/drupal7-master/base_url_generator.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 551 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/sites/default/settings.php).

Warning: include(/var/webroot/drupal7-master/base_url_generator.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 551 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/sites/default/settings.php).

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/webroot/drupal7-master/base_url_generator.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in include() (line 551 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/sites/default/settings.php).

PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/includes/lock.inc).
```

Can anyone help in where or how to solve these errors please

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear, the `base_url_generator.php` file is not found.

Comment: The last errors means the DB username and password are incorrect. Check the settings.php file

Comment: If these files actually exist, check the permission. For the DB error, you might need to set an access rule 'username'@'127.0.0.1' as well.

Answer (score 0):

In setting.php there is a variable $base_url
This variable pointing your domain as wrong location
like in `settings.php` you said you domain name is `drupal7-master`
So Drupal is trying to include files from `/var/webroot/drupal7-master/base_url_generator.php`
But you actual root directory location is `/home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/sites/default/settings.php`

And also trying to find SQL connection credentials in /var/webroot/drupal7-master/sites/default/settings.php

So simply comment this `$base_url` variable or assign correct value to this variable
In my thoughts some one download live site and trying to run at local server without changing `$base_ur` value or comment this line
That's why he/she got these errors

Comment: I commented out the base_url variable in settings.php but noticed it's using dbconfig.php for the db settings so changed them after importing a database the customer had but now just got a blank white page so put the error reporting code in index.php but still just a blank white page and nothing else

Comment: Getting somewhere, I just added $conf['error_level'] = 2; into settings.php and is showing the following errors but unsure how to fix them

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
Original

ParseError: syntax error, unexpected &#039;class&#039; (T_CLASS) in include_once() (line 1 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/sites/all/modules/standard_utilities/user_utilities/classes/UserQuery.php).
Additional

Exception: theme() may not be called until all modules are loaded. in theme() (line 1017 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/includes/theme.inc).

Comment: UPDATE: I commented out the throw new Exception line in theme.inc and just got the following error now if anyone knows a fix for it

    User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: snazzy_form_elements. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1143 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/includes/bootstrap.inc).
    ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in include_once() (line 1 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/sites/all/modules/standard_utilities/user_utilities/classes/UserQuery.php).

Comment: The following module is missing from the file system: snazzy_form_elements:
its mean system: snazzy_form_elements module is installed but not found in modules directory like module directory is removed from directory structure :
Solution one replace the module directory at site/all/modules
Solution two : uninstall this module from database by running sql query how to do this google about it how to uninstall module programmatically

Comment: Oh right ok, is there anyone I can get snazzy form elements module directory to put into sites/all/modules

Not sure if to remove it as it sounds like it's used for a contact form or something

Comment: did'nt find this module in drupal.org so its mean this not a contributed module this a custom created module so you can not download it from web you have to find this from your backups

Comment: Oh right ok, I have asked the customer if they can get a backup of it or something from when the site was originally done

Comment: I got a zip file from the customer who got it from the original developer that is a fix but can't get into the admin as the original developer said it's not needed for the site so I have uploaded the file as they said and then need to go into website control panel to activate this module fix but can't get into that

Comment: All I am getting still is 
    User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: snazzy_form_elements. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1143 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/includes/bootstrap.inc).
    ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in include_once() (line 1 of /home4/adyley/amlcomputersltd.co.uk/sites/all/modules/standard_utilities/user_utilities/classes/UserQuery.php).

Comment: i think your basic question is solved if you have any other issue post new question also this forum is not about to complete you tasks you have to learn drupal basics first give your full effort and than ask question